# Is in JDBC-source-connector generated Avro-Schema stable?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have kafka JDBC sorce connector (DB2) with value AvroConverter.
In config is "query" defined with relative complex SQL.
Connector generated avro-schema on base of Metadata and performed lookup in schema registry.
If exactly same schema wasn't found, connector cant't proceed no more data.
My question is whether generated schema stay stable or schema depends of data input.

For Instance:

`query= „SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(current_date) =  5 THEN 1 ELSE CAST(NULL AS INTEGER) END COL1 FROM SYSIBM. SYSDUMMY1“`

Can be that on 2021-03-05 generated schema is:

```
    {
      "name": "COL1",
      "type": "int"
    }
```

and on 2021-03-06:

```
   {
      "name": "COL1",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Jdbc connector by default reflects the DB table semantics to the Avro generated schema. E.g. if a column is nullable it will generate a schema with an optional field for that column (as you have in the 2nd snippet of code).

Now, if you do sth complex in your query (as you mention), the inferred schema may change indeed. This scenario is the same as changing the DB table schema (e.g. adding a new column or making a column nullable), for this check out the jdbc connector schema evolution docs. Practically, what will happen is that the connector will infer the new avro schema and try to register it to the SR (if auto.register is enabled - by default it is). At that point the Schema Registry (based on the schema compatibility setting it has), will check if the new schema for that subject (e.g. "topicName"-value for a value schema) is compatible with the already latest registered schema. If it is compatible, the new schema registration will be successful and the connector will produce avro messages based on the new avro schema going forwards.